# How to add SQLite C++ library to Eclipse (C++ version)

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-plugin

I need to use SQLite in linux/ubuntu and I want to use sqlite like #include  in my project in eclipse, how can i do that? thanks

Comment: The same way you would add any other third-party library. See [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089717/referencing-3rd-party-libraries-using-relative-paths-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/accessing-sqlite-c) provides a nice description of how to use sqlite3 in a program on linux even though the author advocates for Postgress over SQLite.