# How do I relative reference a library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, relative-path

[image]

I have been asking a lot of questions about LTI-CIVIL and I have figured a solution. For that, I need to relative reference the native library for LTI. Is it possible to relative reference a library in Eclipse ?

If not, what is the workaround ?

Comment: Are you also using ant or maven or other build tool?

Comment: @Jessemon No, I am not.

Comment: Do you want to include LTI in your distributable?  It sounds like you do not want to do that?  How will the user get The LTI jar on their system?

Comment: @Jessemon I will provide the user with a zip file that has *both* jar and LTI. The user can extract it anywhere so I need it to be relative

Comment: @Jessemon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722142/how-to-distribute-native-libraries-with-jar

Comment: @Jessemon I am open to other suggestions, as well. The main aim is to get the thing to work from anywhere and not be limited to Eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This answer will work for you. I know you are not using ant, but you can still specify a CLASSPATH in the manifest of your jar. Include dot in the CLASSPATH, and put the LTI jar in the same folder. That means you can zip up your jar and the LTI jar together at the same outermost level.

If you want the directory structure of your other question, you can put `../putLTIhere` in your CLASSPATH.

This answer will give you more details:

[How to build a distributable jar with Ant for a java project having external jar dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277038/how-to-build-a-distributable-jar-with-ant-for-a-java-project-having-external-jar)

Comment: I actually don't know. I know that if I relative reference the path to native library, I will be able to make my jar distributable

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089717/referencing-3rd-party-libraries-using-relative-paths-in-eclipse-cdt looks like I cannot relative reference anything :/ maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You could use a CLASSPATH according to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277038/how-to-build-a-distributable-jar-with-ant-for-a-java-project-having-external-jar

Comment: Ok, this answer makes sense. Previously, I had only loaded `lti.jar` in Eclipse and I got an `UnsatisfiedLinkException` which means it expects me to do the loading of dll?

Comment: Leave it as is within eclipse. You could make a script or use ant to package your app for distrubution in which you set the CLASSPATH. That mean the dir structure in eclipse and your dist will be different, but is that ok?

Comment: Now that I do not have any options, yes it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the project, then click "properties" -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Absolute path, again! I need to relative path

Comment: An if you try at the last step: add EXTERNAL jar, does that work?